# Add BlurringView in project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-renderscript

Added next dependencies:

```
defaultConfig {
    renderscriptTargetApi 21
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Also:

```
implementation 'com.fivehundredpx:blurringview:1.0.0'
```

In repo:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/raw/master/releases/' }
```

And get error when tried to inflate:

```
    init {
    inflate(context, R.layout.view_authorization_content,this)
    blurringView?.setBlurredView(blurredView)
    blurringView?.invalidate()
}
```

In my code i have:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

If i change on false, all works fine.
Also tried fix with this [solution](https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/issues/15#issuecomment-171693786).

I added in my file `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
```

Also u can check some code from my build(app):

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                // google services plugin is causing missing translation issue
            }
            testCoverageEnabled false
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                // google services plugin is causing missing translation issue
            }
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
```

My error when `minifyEnabled` is `true`:

> Binary XML file line #122: Binary XML file line #122: Error inflating
>   class com.fivehundredpx.android.blur.BlurringView
>       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #122: Error inflating class com.fivehundredpx.android.blur.BlurringView
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: So I guess the BlurringView is somehow getting obfuscated. Can you check it works or not if you add a keep rule for this class

Comment: add `-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }` proguard

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i added, u can check link in solution, which i tried https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/issues/15#issuecomment-171693786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem with next solution:

1) Added in `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class androidx.renderscript.** { *; }
```

2) Modified build.gradle(app):

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: Great to know you solved it :) @Morozov, please accept your own answer so that others facing the same issue find the right answer quickly. Thanks!